# "Check out to matching local branch" not work in "Github Organization" jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

In my jenkins instance, I create a item with type "Github Organization" and configure this jenkins item with Projects > Github Organization > Behaviors > "Check out to matching local branch" as below screenshot

I suppose this setting will help checkout the code from github so I don't include checkout action in the jenkinsfile. However, when the jenkins job is triggred by a github code commit. No source code is checkout.

I have seen another jenkins item created as "Multibranch Pipeline" and configure with "Checkout out to matching local branch." In this case, the code is checked out although the corresponding jenkinsfile doesn't have checkout step.

Please help check why this setting doesn't work in "Github Organization" type jenkins item. Is it a bug? or I make some mistake in the setting.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

answer by myself. The checkout code action is not triggered by "Checking out to match local branch". So even this setting is checked, the checkout code doesn't happen.

In github organization or multi-branch jenkins job, "checkout scm" DSL is used to checkout the code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to add the screenshot when posting message so update my jenkins setting here 
[Jenkins Seeting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSXtw.png)